# Elementos internos sobrepondo a <section>

Tags: css

A tag `<b>` sobrepõe a tag `<section>` veja o exemplo ao eu utilizar `padding`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe na imagem acima que a barra cinza claro refere-se a `section` fica com altura menor que a tag `b`. Ou seja, a tag interna sobrepõe.

Também quando eu redimensiono o navegador a tag `b` sobrepões a ela mesmo, sem dar o espaçamento devido. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<section class="compartilhar">
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
<span>Compartilhar:</span>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section.compartilhar{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

section.compartilhar span{
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Gladison, a tag <b> do HTML é destinada para deixar os elementos em negrito. Preocupe-se em nunca adicionar outros estilos a tag's que ja são definidas para um propósito, crie uma nova classe e atribua esses estilos, isso melhora a interpretação para nós e principalmente para você.

Comment: @Bsalvo Fiz a alteração. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já foi dito, a tag `b`, é destinada a formatação de textos e deve ser manipulada por meio de um container, exemplo...

```css
section.compartilhar{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section.compartilhar div{
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  //box-sizing: border-box
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section class="compartilhar">
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
<div><b>Compartilhar:</b></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Publicou a resposta 2 segundos antes de mim! Hahaha, para complementar: Caso você queira um espaçamento entre elas quando houver a quebra de linha adicione margin-bottom: 5px; (valor opcional).

Comment: kkkk, normal acontece comigo sempre